# URL not changing through NavigationController

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I'm new to Angular and currently developing first web project I'm handling with the next problem:

I have several components and I'm routing between them through NavigationController

```
this.navigationControl.setRoot(myPage)
```

And these components look like this:

```
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'my-page',
  templateUrl: 'myurl.html'
})
```

But instead of `'myurl.html'` I'm getting `localhost:8000/index.html`
what I need to do to make it work?

Comment: `templateUrl` is not what you assume it to be. its for the path of html template to be used in component.

Comment: can you provide an examle please?

Comment: ok, I figured it out, but stil it doesnt work